# When style button is clicked in te7a-houdini/laravel-trix changes are not applied

Tags: laravel-livewire, trix

In Laravel 8 / livewire 2.5 / alpinejs 3 application I use "te7a-houdini/laravel-trix": "^2.0.5",
which is warpper for https://github.com/basecamp/trix
and I found that in livewire blade template having :

```
<div class="p-2 w-full">
    <div class="body-content" wire:ignore>
        <trix-editor
            class="trix-content"
            x-ref="trix"
            wire:model.debounce.1000ms="form.content"
            wire:key="trix-content-unique-key"
        ></trix-editor>
    </div>
    <x-jet-input-error for="form.content" class="mt-2"/>
</div>
```

text entered in trix editor if not applied at form.content var when user clicks on style buttons of trix.
Can it be fixed somehow?
Can I on submit call apply method manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `wire:model.defer` instead of debounce?

Comment: I checked and looks like wire:model.defer did not help here